# How can I define a key-value command like \hypersetup?

Tags: macros, key-value

I am quite familiar with switch (`\if...\else...\fi`) now and read many questions on key-value topic, but I cannot find an example to create the options listing command like `\hypersetup`, to make

```
\documentclass[key1=...,key2=...,key3=...]{myclass}
```

equivalent to

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\myclssetup{%
    key1 = ...,
    key2 = ...,
    key3 = ...,
    .............
}
```

None of these keys are boolean, and all these values helps me to do switch into different layout schemes. For instance, key1 is to set one type of cover page and key2 is to set one type of section formats. I do not need to draw something or to set some geometry properties (I don't need values of numerical parameters). I also want some default options pre-set, if the user didn't specify their options.

If I use the kvoptions package, all I know is that I probably need `\newif` and `\DeclareVoidOption` (kvoptions package) to create options (values), `\define@key` (keyval package) and `\kvsetkeys` command (keyval package) to link values and keys. However, I have been struggling to find similar and simple examples to achieve the function I need.

I think it's important to stress that I am writing a class (not package), and it will be based on another class (like book).

Comment: Do you stick to `kvoptions`?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer No, if it's xkeyval or something else, is all right. But I need to consider some compatibility for users who use old version of TeX distribution (maybe TeX Live 2011/12)

Comment: `xkeyval` has a newer version, but the usage I apply in my answer does rely on that.

Comment: `l3keys` is nice too, but since you're referring to an older TL version, it's perhaps not the correct tool then

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I know that one. Maybe later I would upgrade my class by programming in LaTeX3, with expl3 and others. But since I have a lot to learn even in basic TeX programming and macro manipulation, right now it's probably better to stick to LaTeX2e....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a `xkeyval` version, with automatic definition of keys and it's `keyval` macro and a corresponding `\if...` whether the option is used.

The precise implementation depends on the internal options to be specified what they should do if specified. I assumed, that the class options are to be stored to a macro, say `\classoption@myclass@#2` where  `#2` has the relevant meaning, say `paper` or `width` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\definemykey}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newif\csname ifmyclassname@#1\endcsname
  \define@key{myclass}{#1}{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname classoption@myclass@#2\endcsname{##1}
    \global\expandafter\csname myclassname@#1true\endcsname
  }
}

\definemykey{keyA}{KeyA}
\definemykey{keyB}{KeyB}
\definemykey{keyC}{KeyC}


\newcommand{\myclasssetup}[1]{%
  \setkeys{myclass}{#1}%
}

\makeatother


\myclasssetup{keyB={upvote good answers!}, keyC={provide a MWE}}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\ifmyclassname@keyA
Yes, it was specified
\else
No, it is missing
\fi


\ifmyclassname@keyB
Yes, it was specified and has the value \textbf{\classoption@myclass@KeyB}
\else
No, it is missing
\fi

\makeatother


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think you provide one that is closer to my need, and great MWE demonstration.

Comment: @Spaceship: You're welcome. Happy TeXing

Comment: Hi Christian, You got `legendary` when I was away? Congrats! :)

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thank you very much! Yes, last week. You're back???

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Some what :) . What is the next badge? ^^

Comment: @HarishKumar: I don't know... No gold badge ahead for a long time now.

Answer (score 7):

Examples for `kvoptions` among my packages: `accsupp`, `attachfile2`, `bookmark`, `enparen`, `epstopdf-base`, `grffile`, `pagegrid`, `pmboxdraw`, `rerunfilecheck`, `resizegather`, `selinput`, `zref-xr`, ...

A `grep -r kvoptions TDS:tex/latex` will reveal much more packages.

Example `rerunfilecheck`:

```
% Package start
[...]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{rerunfilecheck}%
  [2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)]

% Option setup
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}[2010/02/22]
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
  family=rerunfilecheck,%
  prefix=ReFiCh@%
}

% The setup command (a convenience wrapper for `\setkeys`:
\newcommand*{\RerunFileCheckSetup}{%
  \setkeys{rerunfilecheck}%
}

% The options
\DeclareBoolOption{mainaux}
\DeclareBoolOption{partaux}
\DeclareBoolOption{starttoc}
\DeclareBoolOption{index}
\DeclareBoolOption{glossary}
\define@key{rerunfilecheck}{aux}[true]{%
  \RerunFileCheckSetup{%
    mainaux={#1},%
    partaux={#1},%
    starttoc={#1},%
    index={#1},%
    glossary={#1}%
  }%
}

% Option processing: first configuration file, then package options
\InputIfFileExists{rerunfilecheck.cfg}{}{}
\ProcessLocalKeyvalOptions*

% Helper macro to disable options
\def\ReFiCh@DisableOption{%
  \DisableKeyvalOption[%
    action=warning,%
    package=rerunfilecheck%
  ]{rerunfilecheck}%
}

[...]

% The options are disabled after they have been used the last time:
\ReFiCh@DisableOption{mainaux}
\ReFiCh@DisableOption{partaux}
\ReFiCh@DisableOption{starttoc}
\ReFiCh@DisableOption{index}
\ReFiCh@DisableOption{glossary}
\ReFiCh@DisableOption{aux}

[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `expkv-opt` you can process package/class options with keys defined for `expkv` (possibly via the helper package `expkv-def`).

An example could be the following class-file stored as `myclass.cls`:

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}

% define the keys (see expkv-def's documentation for an overview on key types)
\ekvdefinekeys{myclass}
  {
     store key1 = \myclassA
    ,store key2 = \myclassB
    ,store key3 = \myclassC
  }
% define the setup macro (will be defined protected here)
\protected\ekvsetdef\myclssetup{myclass}

% process the options given to \documentclass
\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions{myclass}

% lets base on article
\LoadClass{article}

\endinput
```

If used together with this document:

```
\documentclass[key2=def]{myclass}
\myclssetup{key1=abc,key3=ghi}

\begin{document}
\myclassA\par
\myclassB\par
\myclassC\par
\end{document}
```

You'll get

[image]

Please note that in any case (and with any package) the usage of `\documentclass[<options>]{<class>}` and `\documentclass{<class>}\clssetup{<options>}` is *not* the same. Options given to `\documentclass` are (normally) picked up by every package you use (and classes loaded with `\LoadClass`) whereas options given to `\clssetup` don't propagate that way. Also the options given to `\documentclass` will be expanded using `\edef` once (`expkv-opt` doesn't use the expanded option list, but the `raw` one provided by recent versions of LaTeX, still the keys will be expanded inside `\edef` for backwards compatibility), whereas `\clssetup` receives its options as-is.