# Incompatibility between kvoptions and babel

Tags: babel, documentclass-writing, options, kvoptions

I'm using `kvoptions` in my document class and it's worked nicely so far, but after a major rewrite I started getting strange errors that I was able to trace back to the `babel` package.

MWE:

```
%% myclass.cls

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2018/04/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions}

\DeclareStringOption{title}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\LoadClass{article}
\title{\myclass@title}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}

\endinput
```

```
\documentclass[title={Here be dragons}]{myclass}

\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```

An excerpt from the log (paths omitted for brevity):

```
babel.sty:460: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [    {}}]
babel.sty:460: Too many }'s. [    {}}]
babel.sty:475: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [    \ifin@\edef\bbl@tempc{\bbl@tempb}\fi}]
```

Without the `kvoptions` patch, the errors are getting worse:

```
babel.sty:339: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [\ProcessOptions*]
babel.sty:339: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. [\ProcessOptions*]
TeX STOPPED: File ended while scanning use of \reserved@{##1,##2\reserved@b }\def \reserved@b ##1,\reserved@b ##2\reserved@b 
TeX reports the error was in file:3 
myclass.cls:13: LaTeX Error: Unknown option `english' for package `babel'. []
```

**Analysis:** The problem is that I have used spaces (and braces) in the global option (`title`) and this option is obviously passed on to `babel`. Without the spaces, the errors don't occur.

**Question:** Can I prevent document class options from being used as global options by packages? Or is there some work-around akin to `\hypersetup{}` for me to use instead of options? I could live with that.

Comment: Complicated values (with spaces) in the document options are difficult, see e.g. here for a discussion https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/85. But you can always define a `\myclasssetup` command which can process key-val input with one of the various keyval packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by taking inspiration from [an answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309483/how-can-i-define-a-key-value-command-like-hypersetup#309485). Applied to the MWE above, it would look like this:

```
%% myclass.cls

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2018/04/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareStringOption{title}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\LoadClass{article}

\newcommand*{\docsetup}[1]{
  \kvsetkeys{myclass}{#1}
  \title{\myclass@title}
  \RequirePackage[english]{babel}
}

\endinput
```

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\docsetup{title={An awesome title}}

\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```